# How to get length this Json element in Robot Framework

Tags: python, json, robotframework

I would like to get length this json element in Robot Framework.

Json Example

```
[
  [
    {
      "a": "2020-01",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "a": "2020-02",
      "value": "2"
    },
    {
      "a": "2020-03",
      "value": "10"
    },
    {
      "a": "2020-04",
      "value": "9"
    },
    {
      "a": "2020-05",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "a": "2020-06",
      "value": "7"
    }
  ]
]
```

The expected result is

```
a 2020-01
value 1
a 2020-02
value 2
a 2020-03
value 10
a 2020-04
value 9
a 2020-05
value 0
a 2020-06
value 7
```

length = 6

I try

```
${data_length}=      get length       ${json_data}
```

is not working

I think there are [ ] 2 levels. Please guide me, Thanks

Comment: So what result do you expect? Length of 1, or 6? Both are correct, but depends on what you need.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I've added the expected results

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the JSON to a python data structure, and then you can use the `Get Length` keyword on the first element of the outer-most list.

Here's one way to do that. It assumes that the JSON data is not null, and that the raw JSON data is in a variable named `${json_data}`

```
${data}=    Evaluate  json.loads($json_data)
${length}=  Get length  ${data[0]}

Should be equal as numbers  ${length}  6
```

Comment: Evaluate failed: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: @MaherShrubby: without telling me what line caused that problem, I can't help. It sounds like you might have already converted `${json_data}` to a dictionary, in which case you can just ignore the first line in my example. You claimed that `${json_data}` is JSON, which means it's a string. Your error implies it's not.